# How to run docker container inside docker (DIND)?

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I am trying to run a container inside another container using Docker inside docker https://hub.docker.com/_/docker.

When I run the following:

```
docker run --privileged docker:stable-dind docker run hello-world
```

I get the following error message:

docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.

I must be missing something, how can I run docker inside docker?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this in a one-liner (others might correct me). However, as explained at [hub.docker.com/_/docker/](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/), you can start the a docker-in-docker container as a background daemon (`-d`) and then start other containers inside.

To start the parent container, run

```
docker run -d --name some-docker --privileged docker:stable-dind
```

The name `some-docker` is arbitrary. It will be used to identify this container later on. To start a container inside, run

```
docker run  --link some-docker:docker docker run hello-world
```

The `--link` option exposes the network ports of the parent container and sets environment variables, such that the inner container uses docker from the dind image.

Comment: Maybe I should add: there are people who consider docker-in-docker a bad solution in most cases. More about this [here](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) and [here](https://frank.sauerburger.io/2018/06/27/using-docker-in-container.html).