# Run docker in docker on a dedicated server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I will run docker on a dedicated sever by a service provider. It is not
possible to install docker on this server. Apache, Git and a lot more is
installed. So I try to run docker in a container. I will pull a docker image
from the gitlab registry and run in a sub domain. I wrote a .gitlab-ci.yml. But
I get an error message.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858399/10008173):

> You can't (*) run Docker inside Docker containers or images. You can't (*)
>   start background services inside a Dockerfile. As you say, commands like
>   systemctl and service don't (*) work inside Docker anywhere. And in any case
>   you can't use any host-system resources, including the host's Docker socket,
>   from anywhere in a Dockerfile.

How do  I solve this problem?

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: ubuntu:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common

  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add
  - apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
  - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

stages:
    - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-cache search docker-ce
    - apt-get install -y docker-ce
    - docker run -d hello-world
```

Comment: Hi, it works with sudo?

Comment: I tried with sudo, but without success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run docker container inside docker (DIND)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928958/how-to-run-docker-container-inside-docker-dind)

Comment: The usual answer is to give your container access to the host’s Docker socket `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`; given that and appropriate Unix permissions you can launch other containers (and also do whatever you want on the host).

Comment: Hi, could you try attaching DinD as a service?

Answer (score 0):

This .gitlab-ci.yml works for me.

```
image: ubuntu:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/

before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add
  - apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
  - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  - apt-get update

stages:
    - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt-get install -y docker-ce
    - docker info
    - docker pull ...
    - docker run -p 8000:8000 -d --name ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you found.... is a little old. There are options to run systemd in a container and it is also possible to run some [systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script.

However, I am not sure what application you really want to install.